# Join with 3 tables issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I am trying to solve this problem:

"Our data:
We have three Tabels in the database :

```
Plant – describes the possible plants
Planted – whatever the gardener planted
Picked – the crop that was provided after the plantation."
```

What I am trying to do is join to 3 tables like that:

```
SELECT plant.PlantID, plant.name, planted.Seeds, picked.Amount
FROM plant 
INNER JOIN planted ON plant.PlantID = planted.PlantFK
INNER JOIN picked ON picked.PlantFK = plant.PlantID
```

So I could get data about specific PlantID how many seeds was planted and how many was picked.
But for some reason Im getting multiple plantids.
Because the database has more then 1 entry about the plant/ picked about the same PlantID..

How can I fix that join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an aggregate function `SUM` or `COUNT` with a `GROUP BY   plant.PlantID, plant.name` like so:

```
SELECT 
  plant.PlantID, 
  plant.name, 
  SUM(DISTINCT planted.Seeds) 'Planted', 
  SUM(DISTINCT picked.Amount) 'Picked' 
FROM plant 
INNER JOIN planted ON plant.PlantID = planted.PlantFK
INNER JOIN picked ON picked.PlantFK = plant.PlantID
GROUP BY   plant.PlantID, plant.name;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cb3f/4)

If you want to get the plants that have no seeds, and never picked from, you have to use `LEFT JOIN` with `IFNULL()` to get zeros instead of `NULL`s like so:

```
SELECT 
  plant.PlantID, 
  plant.name, 
  SUM(IFNULL(DISTINCT planted.Seeds, 0)) 'Planted', 
  SUM(IFNULL(DISTINCT picked.Amount, 0)) 'Picked' 
FROM plant 
LEFT  JOIN planted ON plant.PlantID = planted.PlantID
LEFT  JOIN picked ON picked.PlantID = plant.PlantID
GROUP BY   plant.PlantID, plant.name;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53464/3)

Comment: I've got this data in my DB
Plant:
Seeds 28 PlantFK 0
Seeds 14 PlantFK 0
Picked:
Amount 52 PlantFK 0 
Amount 12 PlantFK 0

when I'm using your query it looks like the PlantID/PlantFK 0 has 84 planted and 80 picked.
:\

Comment: @DanRevah - Sorry, You have to use `SUM(DISTINCT ...)` [**here is the sample data you posted in your comment**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e318b/3). See my updated answer.

Comment: The first query works but the second one returnes this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT planted.Seeds, 0)) 'Planted', SUM(IFNULL(DISTINCT picked.Amount, 0))' at line 4

Comment: @DanRevah Do you mean the one with the `LEFT JOIN`? What error? post it please. and if possible try to create a demo on the sqlfiddle explaining this issue. Thanks

Comment: @DanRevah - You can't use `DISTINCT` inside the function `IFNULL`. put it outside it inside `SUM` like `SUM(DISTINCT IFNULL(picked.Amount, 0))` instead of `SUM(IFNULL(DISTINCT picked.Amount, 0))`